# Simple access query based on many to many relationship

Tags: ms-access

I have a simple many to many relationship set up on access with "List", "DayJunction" (Junction Table) and "Days". I am trying to query for records in "List" that have no related records in "Days".

[image]

I have tried the following SELECT query:

[image]

and the following COUNT query:

[image]

But neither is giving me the desired result. Is it possible to extract these results using just one query? Also why did the previous two not give me the intended results?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume for the purpose of this answer that these records refer to days in which a particular company attended something.  If that's correct you can do this with two tables instead of three, and it's a one-to-many join if you don't have duplicate company names.  It is perfectly ok to have a many-to-many join if your tables are something like this:

List of companies, `Companies`

```
Company      

Dell
Apple
Google
```

List of attendance by company, `Attendance`

```
Company       Day_attending

Dell          08/01/2016
Dell          08/31/2016
Apple         08/05/2016
Apple         08/08/2016
```

So in this case you'd be looking for `Google` as the output since Google has no attendance records.

Access doesn't know how to do this with the query designer, so you'll have to go into SQL mode and enter the code yourself.  If you were in normal SQL you'd use `EXCEPT`, but Access doesn't support it.  Instead, you can do a funky join by Company value where Company is null.  Like this:

```
SELECT c.Company
FROM Companies as c
LEFT JOIN
Attendance as a
    ON c.Company = a.Company 
    WHERE a.Company is null
```